# Earth Engine API run a task on interval

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-maps, google-earth-engine-python-api

Is there a way using the Earth Engine Python APIs to run every ten days (I'll use chron for scheduling) the following Earth Engine script:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: anomaly10D.first(),
  description: 'anomaly10D',
  scale: 5000,
  region: ROI
});
```

Where *anomaly10D* is an image collection coming from processed CHIRPS data and *ROI* is the Region of Interest (a small country)

To automatically save an **EEAsset** in a specific **folder**, with a specific **filename** and keeping it status to "**Anyone can read**"?

The task should run automatically without any manual confirmation like in the code editor.

**UPDATE 1**

Looking at the API source code I've found the current code more relevant to the task:

```
import ee    

ee.Initialize()    
exportRegion = ee.Geometry.Polygon([...cords of the country...])    
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(
                                     image=anomaly10d.first(),
                                     region= exportRegion.bounds().getInfo()['coordinates'],
                                     description='anomaly10d',
                                     scale=5000, 
                                     crs=myCRS)
task.start()
```

- region is defined differently as in javascript APIs, and we can't pass the geometry object.
- scale can be omitted so it will use the spatial resolution of the source

As noted by Jon, the task will run without asking confirmation.

But there are still a lot of doubts that I'm not able to solve to perform the operation:

1. How can I manage **automatically** the authentication with a google account in Python (no user interaction, as the code run on a server)?
2. How can I set the ACL for the asset to "Anyone can read"?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

1. As long as you have authenticated your system for using Earth Engine (i.e. `earthengine authenticate`) it should run. I am not sure how it behaves with a cron job though...you may want to set up a [service account](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/service_account) and use that to authenticate at the beginning of your script as described in the docs.
2. The Earth Engine Python API comes with a CLI that lets you set the access control list (ACL) of your assets, you just need to call it from your Python script using the following code.

```
import os

os.system('earthengine acl set public {}'.format(assetId))
```